# First column of linear transform matrix is zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $(v_1, v_2,\ldots, v_m)$ is an ordered basis of $V$, and $(w_1, w_2,\ldots, w_n)$ is an ordered basis of $W$. If the transform matrix from $V$ to $W$ has a first column of all $0$'s, what are the implications for the basis vectors? All I can think of is that the first element of each $v_i$ in $V$ is irrelevant in the the transform. Can someone give the general idea of what it means?

The original question is that $(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$ is a basis of V. The transform matrix of dimension n x m from V to W has the first column all 0s or a one in the first column first row. Prove that there exists a basis $(w_1,\ldots, w_n)$ of W.

Comment: What is the transformation matrix from $V$ to $W$?

Comment: $v_1$ is in the kernel of the transformation.

Comment: You, don’t know anything about the matrix other than the first column is all 0. I think there different cases to consider depending on the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: The original question is different, but I’m trying to figure it out. I can make an edit including the original question.

Comment: I guess implicitly the original question is implying that the $n \times m$ matrix is either full row rank or full column rank, and then if $m \geq n$ it is surjective. Maybe the term 'Transform' matrix implies this with reference to some specific source...